# Connect to MS SQL Server on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, ms-sql

I installed on my arch machine `mssql-server` and `mssql-tools` via `yaourt`. I started the server from `/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr` and tried to connect with my credentials, but with no luck. I found [this](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ms-sql-server-centos-ubuntu-linux/) article which says to connect with the command `sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'YourPasswordHere'`, but it didn't work either. The error message says:

> 2017-07-06 21:57:28.25 Logon Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7.
>
> 2017-07-06 21:57:28.25 Logon Login failed for user 'SA'. Reason: An
>   error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]

I tried with blank password, with Password123 and with my user's password but the message was the same.

Has anyone managed to connect and if yes what was the default password?

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

found it. I had to run this command `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup` in order to set the password for the SA user. Now I can connect.